# Code works fine in VS 2008 but not in later versions of VS

Tags: c++, qt

The following code works fine in VS 2008 but in later versions it gives error (C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'overloaded-function' to 'TQStringArgFnPtr'
None of the functions with this name in scope match the target type)

I am absolutely confused why. Can somebody help me what the hell differences are there between vs2008 and later v.?

```
#include <QtCore>

typedef QString (QString::*TQStringArgFnPtr)(const QString &, int, const QChar &) const ;
TQStringArgFnPtr QStringArgFnPtr =  &QString::arg;
```

Comment: IIRC, VC++ will show you all overloads it knows about.

Answer (score 2):

In this situation, the assignment should be enough to disambiguate the chosen function overload. It's one reason why I first thought about a compiler bug (the second one being VS).

However, a careful reading of the documentation shows that this particular overload of `Qstring::arg` has changed signature, from :

```
QString QString::arg(
    const QString & a,
    int fieldWidth = 0,
    const QChar & fillChar = QLatin1Char( ' ' )
) const
```

... in [Qt 4.8](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html#arg), to :

```
QString QString::arg(
    const QString & a,
    int fieldWidth = 0,
    QChar fillChar = QLatin1Char( ' ' ) // no more reference !
) const
```

... in [Qt 5.4](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#arg). The first overload isn't present anymore.

Which makes me conclude that your different VS version point at different Qt versions that are incompatible in this aspect.

Comment: `code`#if (QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(5, 0, 0))
  typedef QString (QString::*TQStringArgFnPtr)(const QString &, int, const QChar &) const ;
#else
  typedef QString (QString::*TQStringArgFnPtr)(const QString &, int, QChar) const ;
#endif
TQStringArgFnPtr QStringArgFnPtr =  &QString::arg;

Comment: @DianaLlubpet looks fine to me !